# how do I upload a file from GSC Bucket to Google Drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a file that gets updated every 30 minutes. I'm trying to figure out how to upload this file to a google drive folder whenever it gets updated in the GCS Bucket using Google Cloud Function but im relatively new to google cloud and automation.

Comment: The use-case seems pretty clear. Did you try anything already?

Answer (score 2):

You must first configure the bucket so that each time a new file is uploaded a trigger to a cloud function starts.

> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage?hl=it

Then you have to give the cloud function the right permissions by creating a service account via IAM that has permissions to write to google drive.

Finally write the code ( into cloud function ) using the google library to do the upload.

Here you can find an indication of how to do this, the snippet is then written in python

> https://www.thecloudverse.com/gcs-to-gdrive/

I hope I was helpful

Comment: thank you! I saw this post but I don't have a python background to be honest so didnt know how to apply the python code in cloud function

Comment: What language do you need to write it in?